# Looking for a short story about a 'homecoming' song from an anthology published pre-1990

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

This is a short story dating back to the 1980s or earlier - I read it in my school library in the late 80s/very early 90s. It's about a world in which underdeveloped planets were forced to hand over children for adoption to wealthy offworlders. They are told to have a 'birthday party' for two year olds who are then taken away. The first scene is, indeed, a family trying to have a 'par-ty' for a small child who is then taken.

Many years later, few of the adopted children know they were adopted. One of the children - perhaps the child taken in the first scene? - meets an old friend of his in a bar who is talking about composing a song about searching for home. The song becomes very popular and suddenly these people start feeling a need to find somewhere they barely remember. The story ends with news that a planet which had been thought of as nearly empty was erupting into rebellion as these missing children return.

It was one of a collection of short stories in an anthology that I found in my school library in the UK in the late 80s/early 90s. I think the cover had an image that looked like a tree lit up in the dark but I'm not sure.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site, please take the [tour] and visit the [help], also we would still appreciate you [edit]ing in an more details from this [list](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/3804) to help us find the story you're looking for, such as where and when you read it.

Comment: Are both of the stories you have asked about in the same anthology?

Comment: I'm not sure. I think they might be, but because it was so long ago I couldn't be certain, which was why I asked about them separately.

Comment: @SallyTP just so you know, even if they were in the same anthology, asking about them separately would still have been the right course of action :D